# cylindrical texture mapping opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, cylindrical

I am trying to do a texture mapping in opengl, using a cylinder as an intermediate surface, that is,

theta =(atan2(z1,x1)) + M_PI ; 
h = (y1);
Here, x1, y1, z1 are the x,y,z of a vertex.

u = theta , v = h
[Here is the texture I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cThQ3.jpg)

This is how the cup got textured:

[image]

Why is there a discontinuous patch in the texture map?

Comment: Magic 8 ball says, "Without a doubt." Not very helpful, admittedly, but it's the best I can do with what I've got to work with. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there a discontinuous patch in the texture map?

Because you're wrapping your texture coordinates from something close to 1 back to 0. The "gap" is there, because you didn't add a gap into your geometry. You'll have to split up the geometry and add a seam where your angular texture coordinate goes to 1.